bigquery data transfer service is not syncing with Teradata extraction in Python
The need is to extract the data from Teradata to bigquery using bigquery data transfer service BQ DTS in my python code.
what I faced the problem here is I am unable to pass teradata connection details when data_source_id="on_premises".
I have researched a lot for correct config but could not find it web. Not sure what other source ID can be used.
with above code the transfer is still running for a long time and the failing.
here is my code snippet.
# Transfer configuration parameters
transfer_config = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.TransferConfig(
    destination_dataset_id=dataset_id,
    display_name="my_transfer",
    data_source_id="on_premises",  # Ensure 'on_premises' is correct for your use case
    params={
        "database_type": mybase,
        "bucket": my_bucket,
        "table_name_patterns": teradata_table  # Ensure this is in the correct format
    },
)

# Create the transfer configuration
try:
    response = client.create_transfer_config(parent=parent, transfer_config=transfer_config)
    print(f"Created transfer config: {response.name}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error creating transfer config: {e}")
    raise


